# Keep track of element bindings and event states in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events

I have an angular application which behaves as follows:

- on `mousedown` a request gets send, returning JSON data representing the updated object.
- while event still is active, element gets re-rendered with received data.
- on `mouseup` again a request is sent, JSON is received and element gets rendered again.

I implemented this via directives like this:

```
var PRESS_EVENT = 'mousedown';
var RELEASE_EVENT = 'mouseup';

app.directive('ngPress', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, $element, $attributes) {
            $element.bind(PRESS_EVENT, function(event) {
                $scope.$eval($attributes.ngPress);
            });
        }
    };
});

app.directive('ngRelease', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, $element, $attributes) {
            $element.bind(RELEASE_EVENT, function(event) {
                $scope.$eval($attributes.ngRelease);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Template code looks like:

```
<div data-ng-press="press(uid)"
     data-ng-release="release(uid)">
    ...
</div>
```

While this works fine in browsers properly firing `mousedown` and `mouseup`, this fails to work on devices with a touchscreen where `touchstart` and `touchend` are these event's substitutes (almost, read on).

As described here - http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webevents/2012OctDec/0023.html - `touchend` is promised to be fired on the same element it was treiggered on - actually the one just removed due to re-rendering, and it also not bubbles up the DOM because there is no parent element any longer.

Now I'm searching for a way keeping track of the removed element - either by keeping it unless `touchend` occurs or maybe something fancier transferring the actual event state to the referred new element.

Now I want to register a destroy listener in `ngPress` doing the job:

```
var PRESS_EVENT = 'touchstart';
var RELEASE_EVENT = 'touchend';

app.directive('ngPress', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, $element, $attributes) {
            $element.bind(PRESS_EVENT, function(event) {
                $scope.$eval($attributes.ngPress);
            });
            $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
                // do my fancy magic here
            });
        }
    };
});

...
```

How can I access the related event handlers and/or event state for later reuse after re-rendering or how do I keep element to listen to `touchend` as expected?

Comment: How can I emulate touch events delay?

Comment: Have you considered hiding it, instead of removing it?

Comment: @MWay yes i did. It's going to be removed during the re-rendering of the scope which is performed to angular in this case. That's also meant with "how do i keep element to listen to touchend as expected" in my last sentence. I Just don't know what's the correct hook in angular to achieve this?

Comment: @rnix: I believe a fiddle might shed some light on what is going on...

Answer (score 0):

A directive was implemented to control touch events, it is ngTouch. You can find more information here:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch

Comment: thanks for the hint. i've already seen this. although i have not taken a deeper look at the implementation, i fear this does not solve the underlying problem of lost event firing if bound element has been removed.